# click all buttons on page except when parent has a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to click all buttons on a page that have the attribute `data-capture='noiseClicked'`

This is my code so far:

```
javascript: (function() {
    var followButtons = $("li.js-profile-card button[data-capture='noiseClicked']");
    var index = followButtons.length - 1;
    follow();

    function follow() {
        if (index >= 0) {
            $(followButtons[index--]).click();
            setTimeout(follow, 1);
        }
    }
})();
```

However I want to exclude buttons that have a parent of `li.noise--active` or `li.friend--active`

So the following would be clicked:

```
<li class="js-profile-card noise--active"><button data-capture="noiseClicked" type="button"></button></li>
```

but the following would not be clicked...

```
<li class="js-profile-card noise--active"><button data-capture="noiseClicked" type="button"></button></li>
```

or

```
<li class="js-profile-card friend--active"><button data-capture="noiseClicked" type="button"></button></li>
```

I thought that jquery's not selector would be helpful here, but I'm not sure how to use it to exclude a parent element with a specific attribute and I don't know how to exclude two different attributes (`noise--active` and `friend--active`)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) & [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) methods for this:

```
var indexToSet = index--;
if( !$(followButtons[indexToSet]).parent().hasClass( 'noise--active' ) && !$(followButtons[indexToSet]).parent().hasClass( 'friend--active' )) {
    $(followButtons[indexToSet]).click();
 }
```

EDIT:

to travel up in the node list better to use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

```
var indexToSet = index--;
if( !$(followButtons[indexToSet]).closest( 'noise--active' ).length && !$(followButtons[indexToSet]).closest( 'friend--active' ).length ) {
    $(followButtons[indexToSet]).click();
 }
```

Comment: wow, that was quick. I'm a little confused as to where to put your code in my example as it's quite different. What does the `var indexToSet = index--;` do? Should I put this in the `if (index >= 0) {` loop within the `follow()` function? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, put this inside that `if` statement in follow function instead of `$(followButtons[index--]).click();` line. `var indexToSet = index--;` is temp variable to use `index` later as I need to use it in few places and using `index--` will decrement that value each time I use

Comment: ah, ok, that makes sense. I've not got it quite working unfortunately, because the `noise--active` class is in the great grand parent element. In order to keep the question as simple as possible I assumed saying it was just a parent would be ok. Is there a way to get this working for the following: `<li class="js-profile-card noise--active"><div class="something"><div class="somethingelse"><nav class="other"><button data-capture="noiseClicked" type="button"></button></nav></div></div></li>`

Answer (score 1):

`:not` selector might come handy:

```
var followButtons = $("li.js-profile-card:not(.noise--active,.friend--active) button[data-capture='noiseClicked']");
```